# Bash daily cron at specific period of time on Openshift

Tags: bash, openshift

I know how to run cron at specific time, but I don't know how to random run it once a day between 10:00 AM to 10:30 AM on openshift ?

Run at specific time:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ `date +%H:%M` == "10:00" ]
then
######## do stuff here
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
time=$(date +%H:%M)
IFS=":"
time=($time)
if [[ ${time[0]} == 10 && ${time[1]} -le 30 ]]
then
######## do stuff here
fi
```

Or using **grep**:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(echo $(date +%H:%M) | grep "10:[0-2][0-9]") ]]; then
########time range is 10:00 to 10:29
######## do stuff here
echo "doing stuff here"
fi
```

If you want exactly 10:00 to 10:30 using grep, then change the `if` to:

```
if [[ $(echo $(date +%H:%M) | grep -e "10:[0-2][0-9]" -e "10:30" ) ]]; then
```